# Partial UI screen up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

In a screen, I have a edit text on top (large contains space for 4-5 line), image view below that and submit button at bottom. on Keyboard up it should not hide my submit button.

when keyboard appears i am able to resize the window using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` which allow me not to hide the submit button but it resize my image also which i don't want.

Only submit button should move up when keyboard is visible without resizing image.

I tried frame layout also but it didn't may be i tried wrong way. Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this and let me know is it still happening or not .

**activity_mian.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/xxx.jpg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_app" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_textbox"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_textbox"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_remember"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="  Remember Me"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />    


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_login" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

set your Button, EditText etc.. inside one linear layout followed by one parent ScrollView .

one another thing is that set    **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"**
inside your java file where your xml file is bind .

Comment: Thanks for your solution with some changes it worked so please edit answer .

Comment: kindly except the answer if it it use full for you .@CodingRat

Comment: 1) Root layout as normal in my case Relative layout. Then scroll view inside scroll view take a Linear layout where specify edit text + image View. Then bottom button.

Comment: 2) android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: 3) disable scroll in java code using mScrollView.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                  return true;
            }
});

Comment: sorry comment doesnt allow that much big xml

Comment: if you agree then feel free to like my answer :) and thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 1):

With some changes in @jigs answer i got it working and posting may be it can help others like me

1) Root layout as normal in my case Relative layout. Then scroll view inside scroll view take a Linear layout where specify edit text + image View. Then bottom button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewNotScrollable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/user_name_container">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/feed_hint"
            android:imeActionLabel="Submit"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/feed_sub_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/light_gray"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            <!--<ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:padding="4dp"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                >-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <!--</ScrollView>-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgPreview"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPreview"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/closeimage"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_name_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feed_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="san-serif-condensed"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="sherry's phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_name_size"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_user_name_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="san-serif-condensed"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="sherry's phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_name_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/editname" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_update_block"
        android:fontFamily="san-serif-medium"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2)android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in your manifest.xml

3) disable scroll in java code (optional)

```
    mScrollView.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                  return true;
            }
});
```