# how to avoid overlap Enter EditText window should not overlap with layout in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

When i enter `EditText` box for typing window is overlap with layout .How to solve this overlapping issue with soft keyboard.

Here is image of layout.

[image]

I have tried  this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in particular activity tag in `manifest.xml` file .How to avoid such over lapping issues.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_one"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#3A86CF">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBack_AllPostDetails"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_Vesselname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Vessel name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|normal" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative_one"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/itemview_imgProFilePic"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_round_corner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/avtaaar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_textInspectorName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemview_imgProFilePic"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
                    android:paddingLeft="7sp"
                    android:text="Birger"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_textSpChar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_textInspectorName"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
                    android:text="@string/my_string"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_textNotation"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_textSpChar"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|clip_vertical|left"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Notation"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_txt_Date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|right"
                    android:paddingRight="6sp"
                    android:text="DATE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_textDescid"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />


                <com.example.SlideMenuDemo.ExpandableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_textRemark"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/item_textInspectorName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemview_imgProFilePic"
                    expandableTextView:animAlphaStart="1"
                    expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="Birger"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"

                        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                </com.example.SlideMenuDemo.ExpandableTextView>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageLay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/item_hlist"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:measureAllChildren="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/item_innerlay"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttonslayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageLay"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:focusable="false" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgButton_FoloowUp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/follow_up_grey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textFollowCount"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imgButton_StarRateEquipment"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="RG"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgButton_RecordAudio"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                    android:src="@drawable/recorder_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAudioCount"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgButton_Camera"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera_grey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtImageCount"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:padding="6sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewAllPostItem"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/follow_post"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonslayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:padding="5dp"></ListView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/follow_post"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_FollowUpmessage"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="text|textCapWords|textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="10"
                    android:maxLength="140"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text="Enter text here."
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPostFollowUp_ItemDetail"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                        android:text="Post"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

<!--
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
    ></RelativeLayout>
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"  >-->
```

Comment: Try this....android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: post your xml for the activity

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037424/partial-ui-screen-up/34039755#34039755 facing same issue,accept answer if works in ur case :) @p. ld

Comment: and also use scroll layout

Comment: when i used scroll view then listview does not show .

Answer (score 0):

If this EditText is inside ScrollView than similar issue occured with me, i have tried following code ,

In your **AndroidManifest** file add this to your activity,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

---

Now , in your class try following code as per your ID's you have given in xml,

```
editMsj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMsj);
        editMsj.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.editMsj) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still getting same issue.

Comment: i have resolved my issue like as in above answer. let me search more on this we will solve it @p.ld